# App suddenly does not respond to orientation change Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

A while back, when we were first testing our app, the screen used to rotate when we tilted the phone.  Even if the portrait formatting wasn't so great, it still responded to the orientation change.

I have no idea what happened between that point and this, but it no longer responds to orientation changes, at all.  If I tilt the phone, it stays in portrait mode and does not rotate at all, the text does not align to the new orientation.

This is across all platforms, and I have the proper settings selected for each specific platform (in iOS in the info.plist, and in Android with the MainActivity decorations.)

The one thing I did do is that moved all of my screens from StackLayout-based to FlexLayout-based.  But the screen SHOULD still rotate, or at least ATTEMPT to rotate, should it not?  And this happens across all screens.

So ... if I may please could get some advice about what may be happening, here, that causes this behavior across all platforms?

It should be noted that we are also using Telerik libraries for many of our controls (but I don't know why it would make a difference.)

Also, it's a shared app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.  Rotation was locked.